# Is there a way to destruct and then move construct a polymorphic base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, placement-new

What I want to do is give some classes in an existing hierarchy the ability to reinitialize one of their base classes via a member function. I know this would be a bad design decision if starting from a green field. I want to know if there are any tricks to get it to work any way.

Here is my naive attempt:

```
class Base {
    const int i_;
    std::unique_ptr<int> ui_;
public:
    Base() :i_{ 0 }{}
    Base(int i) :i_{ i }{}
    Base(Base && other) :i_{ other.i_ }, ui_{ std::move(other.ui_) }{}
    virtual void f(){
        std::cout << "Base f";
    }
    virtual ~Base(){
        std::cout << "Base dtor";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void f(){
        std::cout << "Derived f";
    }
    void reinitializeBase(Base && other){
        static_cast<Base*>(this)->Base::~Base(); //only call bases dtor
        new (static_cast<Base*>(this)) Base(std::move(other));
    }
    virtual ~Derived(){
        std::cout << "Derived dtor";
    }
};
```

the problem is obviously that the base classes constructor corrupts the pointer to vtable (making it point to base rather than derived).

I am aware that the "right" way to do this would be to pass the parameters for bases constructor in through the constructor of the derived class. This is not possible because Derived classes are created by a factory which I cannot modify. I could also just move the contents of the unique pointer in without reconstructing the base but then I still couldn't modify the `const int`

EDIT:
sorry I forgot to mention that I cannot modify the base class either.

Comment: You cannot modify the base class? Surely you can remove that nasty little `const` from the file `base.h`. Nobody has to know...

Comment: @PorkyBrain It seems, that you have a huge design flaw in your architecture. If you in some way succeed and call ctors and dtors from within live class I bet, that you'll have a lot of problems in the future. This *has* to be solved in a different way.

Comment: @rodrigo Problem is that base comes from someone else's library so if I change it and someone updates the change is gone.

Comment: @Spook I agree (and stated in my post) that this is generally a dumb idea but its a tiny part part of a minimal work proof of concept of a design change. If the concept works everything will be changed to clean code including this monstrosity.

Comment: And can't you to that that someone? If they are from outside your organization you could manage a patch-set over the library. That's a relatively frequent thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

And no hack you can do would be safer than modifying `base.h` for your own private use in a ABI compatible way and making `base` better behaved.  This requires knowledge of your compilers ABI and all future ABIs your code would be compiled under, which is impossible for any non trivial project.

If your life depended on it, you could do it: but doing it reliably would require constant vigilence against ABI changes.  In practice, I would change `base`, or do `pImpl` hiding of `base`, or stop using `base`.

Comment: I am accepting this because the more I think about it the more this seems like more harm than good even for a quick fix, patching Base allows a whole host of trivial solutions. This answer best depicts my attempt as generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the new information:
Write a Wrapper class that has as member de 'Base' class.

The wrapper can have set/get function to access/change the internal 'Base' class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly but if Base is a member variable rather than a base class then I can no longer convert a pointer to derived to a pointer to base.

Comment: wouldn't that mess up all virtual function calls on the base pointer?

Comment: there are no virtual function calls to the base pointer. Base is a member, no polymorphic pointer. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: Making a pointer to base non polymorphic is an unacceptable design change. Plus if I were to make Base non polymorphic it would solve the original problem of the vtable pointer anyway (because there would be none) so I wouldn't need the adapter patter in that case either.

Comment: Then the only solution I can think of is: If you need a new base class in the derived class. Throw away the derived class and create a new derived class.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However I can't solve the problem by changing the derived class because no matter how I change it I can't change the arguments that its constructor takes because it is created by a templetized factory function.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function `Reset` on the base class, this way you have more control about what you want to reinitialize

Comment: a member function would not be able to initialize const members

Comment: const members should not be reinitialized, they are const after all

Comment: `EDIT: sorry I forgot to mention that I cannot modify the base class either.`